# Heroku local failing with no error message

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to get a flask structure up and running with Heroku following their guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o

but I'm encountering a weird problem, following the guide, I get the following error when running `heroku local`:

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
```

with no additional messages. I'm on windows 7 64bit and tried running it from both gitbash and cmd with and without "run as administrator ", but nothing changes.

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn main:app --log-file -
```

folder structure is pretty much the standard:

```
.git/
static/
venv/
main.py
Procfile
```

and main.py is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return 'hello world'
```

Now when I tried calling app.run to run flask manually, it worked fine with no problems.. Any idea to what might be causing this?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your issue, I'm not a Heroku user but `Gunicorn` doesn't run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the behavior if your procfile is blank. Check that and reset it if needed.